# Big-O Notation, integration, proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

Can anyone figure out how to prove that the 
$$\int_{\sqrt x}^x \frac{1}{\log^2(t)} dt = O\left(\frac{x}{\log^2(x)}\right)$$

Comment: Your RHS cannot depend on t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: use $ (1/\log x)' = -1/(x\log^2 x) $ to "solve" the integral, then have a look at [LogIntegral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion)

Comment: well the next part of the question uses Li(x) and asks to prove it so I cant exactly use it to prove the above question. is there another way?

Comment: you could try to prove that the ratio converges to a nonzero constant, perhaps with the help of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule